# how to define categories in R when the string is variable?

Tags: r

I have a long list of gene names in col4 in my table, I want to categorize them in a new column (col6)using R.

my table:

```
col1      col2     col3     col4          col5
scf001    74212    85524    Jockey-1_DAzt   -
scf002    35002    48200    Jockey-4B_DVi   +
scf0101   82177    82314    BEL-1_DVir-I    -
scf00273  63849    29746    BEL-2_DEl-I     +
scf002    71524    73526    Mariner-2_DVi   +
scf0101   1172     1372     Mariner-9_DAn   -
scf00273  1        4356     ULYSSES_LTR     +
```

here my genes names are highly variable and only part of the name is definable,
I tried this but it doesn't work, the error is that `all arguments must have the same length`

and how can I put the new categories in the new column?

```
df[["col6"]]<-0
table(df$col6, c("Jockey"="category1","BEL"="category2","ULYSSESS"="category2","Mariner"="category3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from dplyr and `str_detect` from stringr.

```
df2 = df %>%
  mutate(col6 = case_when(
    str_detect(col4, "Jockey") ~ "category1",
    str_detect(col4, "BEL") ~ "category2",
    ...
    TRUE ~ ""))
```

The second argument in `str_detect` can be a string or a regular expression.

The last line is to assign a category if nothing matches.

Comment: thanks it worked, can you please explain what is the " %>%" function? I have seen it in other packages like tidyverse

Comment: This is pipe operation. You can read about it [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html), for example.